# Potential for $A\,\nabla V$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, differential-forms, vector-fields

Let $V:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ smooth, let $A$ invertible real matrix of dimension $n\times n$. Consider the following vector field $F:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^ n$,
$$ F(x) \equiv A\,\nabla V(x) \,.$$
Is it possible to determine some condition on $A$ such that $F$ has a potential, namely there exists $U:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ such that
$$ \nabla U(x) = F(x) \;\;?$$
In particular I am interested in the case $A$ diagonal matrix.

Comment: The diagonal case will work, but the general case will not. If you rotate a conservative force field $\pi/2$ in the plane, the resulting vector field will only be conservative if you started with the gradient of a harmonic function.

Comment: Oh, I take it back. Even the diagonal case is doomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is helplessly false, even in the diagonal case. Here are two examples (following up on my comments).

(1) Take $V(x,y)=\frac12(x^2+y^2)$ and $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1\\1& 0\end{bmatrix}$. Then
$$A\nabla V = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1\\1& 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -y\\x\end{bmatrix}$$
is not conservative.

Note, however, that if we stick with the rotation matrix and take $V$ to be harmonic, then $A\nabla V$ will again have curl $0$. For example, with $V(x,y)=\frac12(x^2-y^2)$, we get $A\nabla V = \begin{bmatrix} y\\x \end{bmatrix} = \nabla(xy)$. No coincidence that we get the harmonic conjugate here.

(2) Take $V(x,y) = xy$ and $A=\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & b\end{bmatrix}$. Then
$$A\nabla V = \begin{bmatrix} a & 0\\ 0 & b \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} y\\x\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} ay\\bx\end{bmatrix}$$
is not conservative unless $a=b$.

Comment: Thank you! In the 2d case you can say that a vector field is conservative or not by computing its curl. Is there an analogous fast method in general dimension d?

Comment: In 2D and in 3D, the curl will work (as long you're in a simply connected domain). In higher dimensions, you need to use differential forms and compute the exterior derivative of the $1$-form. Again, assuming simple connectivity, it will be exact precisely when it's closed.